# Transparent Activity but background activity switch to fullscreen

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activities: A and B

A uses style: **Appcompat.Light.DarkActionBar windowActionBar false, windowNoTitle true**.

B uses style: **Theme.Translucent windowActionBar false, windowNoTitle false**.

I used A to call B, but when B appeared on the screen, activity A seem like change to fullscreen.

How can i only show activity B without affecting A?[image]

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: hope you have  create two style.xml because Theme.Translucent windowActionBar is support in v19 or later devices. now in manifest you can give your theme  to both activity.

Comment: See this link, will help you. Possible duplicate- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: You need to create two styles for both activity.

Comment: I don't know why you guys voted down my question. But i said i used different style on each activity (i customed it  in style.xml).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to configure dynamically.this is small snippet of code you follow like this. This code is not exact.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
{
    // Hide the status bar
    getWindow().setFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // Hide the action bar
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
else
{
    // Hide the status bar
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    / Hide the action bar
    getActionBar().hide();
}
```

Or you can refer from [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

Comment: My question is how to keep the StatusBar there, not hiding.
But with your code, i think i found the way to fix it. Tks anyway.